# "Overwrite" repeated values in a file (C)

Tags: c, file, overwrite

Hello i have a little problem, and i cannot find a solution yet. I have a file (data.txt) with the next information:

```
5,5,6,2,5,2
1,4,2,3,7,2
4,2,5,2,3,4
5,5,6,2,5,2
4,5,2,6,2,4
2,1,5,6,3,2
```

And i want to set to 0 all the repeated lines, for example: 5,5,6,2,5,2 appears two times, so the final file must look as follows:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0
1,4,2,3,7,2
4,2,5,2,3,4
0,0,0,0,0,0
4,5,2,6,2,4
2,1,5,6,3,2
```

I have tried with auxiliar files but cannot get the solution, i would be so apreciated with any help.

I can set any of the two lines to 0 but not both of them, and the same if the same line appears more than twice.

Comment: Please post the code you've already written.

Comment: What is the width and the height of the matrix in the input file? Is it always the same width? Is it always the same height?

Comment: What is your problem?, What do you expect of us?

Comment: show the code that sets *each of them to zeros but not both*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by:

- Opening the input/output file on `"r+"` mode first
- Systematically getting characters from the file line by line into an array of character arrays
- Comparing lines with each other, setting characters other than commas to zero characters when they are paired
- Seeking back in the file
- Writing lines back into the file, separating them with new lines

To detect pairings properly, you could possibly follow the following logic:

- Pick a line, create a variable along with it and set it to `1`
- Compare that line with the others
- In case of a match, set the variable to `0` and keep on comparing your line with the rest
- ... until the end, replacing the non-comma characters to zero characters with each match
- After checking with them all, modify or don't modify your initially picked line depending on the state of that variable which you had set to `1` initially

Here's a code that works, should work without flaw unless you have insufficient memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

void settozero( char * line ) {
    for ( int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++ )
        if ( line[i] != ',' )
            line[i] = '0';
}

int main( ) {

    char ** lines = NULL;
    FILE * input;

    if ( ( input = fopen( "input", "r+" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "error at line %d", __LINE__ );
        return -1;
    }

    int currentchar;
    int newline = 1;
    int linecount = 0;
    int lineindex;
    int linesize;
    while ( ( currentchar = fgetc( input ) ) != EOF ) {
        if ( newline ) {
            linecount++;
            lineindex = 0;
            linesize = 128;
            lines = realloc( lines, linecount * sizeof * lines );
            lines[linecount - 1] = malloc( linesize );
            newline = 0;
        }
        if ( lineindex == linesize ) {
            linesize *= 3;
            lines[linecount - 1] = realloc( lines[linecount - 1], linesize );
        }
        if ( currentchar == '\n' ) {
            newline = 1;
            currentchar = '\0';
        }
        lines[linecount - 1][lineindex++] = currentchar;
    }

    if ( !newline ) {
        if ( lineindex == linesize )
            lines[linecount - 1] = realloc( lines[linecount - 1], linesize + 1 );
        lines[linecount - 1][lineindex] = '\0';
    }

    int * linestoskip = calloc( linecount, sizeof * linestoskip );

    for ( int i = 0; i < linecount; i++ ) {
        if ( linestoskip[i] )
            continue;

        int unique = 1;
        for ( int j = i + 1; j < linecount; j++ ) {
            if ( linestoskip[j] )
                continue;

            if ( strcmp( lines[i], lines[j] ) == 0 ) {
                unique = 0;
                settozero( lines[j] );
                linestoskip[j] = 1;
            }
        }
        if ( !unique )
            settozero( lines[i] );
    }

    free( linestoskip );
    fseek( input, 0L, SEEK_SET );

    for ( int i = 0; i < linecount; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; lines[i][j] != '\0'; j++ ) {
            fputc( lines[i][j], input );
        }
        if ( i != linecount - 1 || newline )
            fputc( '\n', input );
        free( lines[i] );
    }

    free( lines );

    putchar( 10 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @LuisIbarra You're welcome bro, but this really isn't the way you should be asking questions here. You should show your failed attempt that you've been working on. I really shouldn't have answered it like this, but I did it anyway since I thought that it might help and I had time.